# Inverse Matrices - Find Matrix $X$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose we have 3 square matrices $A,X,Y$, and suppose that $A,X$ and $(A-AX)$ are invertible. In addition, $(A-AX)^{-1} = X^{-1}B$

Find $X$

Now if you were to assume $B$ is invertible, you could simply do the following:
$$(A-AX)^{-1} = X^{-1}B$$
$$I = (A-AX)X^{-1}B$$
$$I = AX^{-1}B-AB$$
$$AX^{-1}B = I + AB$$
Now we take the inverse of everything, which is the step that confuses me (how can we do that if it wasn't given that $B$ is invertible?)
$$B^{-1}XA^{-1}=(I+AB)^{-1}$$
$$X = B(I+AB)^{-1}A$$

Would appreciate it if someone could explain to me why we can just take the inverse of $B$ here.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $B=X(A-AX)^{-1}$ is centainly invertible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$(A - AX)^{-1} = X^{-1}B$$

$$X(A - AX)^{-1} = X(X^{-1}B)$$

$$X(A - AX)^{-1} = X(X^{-1}B)$$

$$X(A - AX)^{-1} = (XX^{-1})B$$

$$X(A - AX)^{-1} = IB$$

$$X(A - AX)^{-1} = B$$

The last line shows that B is the product of two invertible matrices. Therefore, it is invertible.